# VS 2012, Object Browser, How to determine which members(methods, properties) are inherited?

Tags: inheritance, visual-studio-2012, objectbrowser

I'm using Object Browser in Visual Studio 2012 to get the idea of what a class/interface is, who is its parent etc.
There is a way to show inherited methods and properties by checking "Show Inherited Members" in settings.

However I can't understand **how to differentiate members that are inherited from members that were created for this class** ?

I'd like to group them by Inherited/Not Inherited characteristic or at least to make different icons for inherited members.
Is there a way to do this? May be even by using some other tool ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there should be no way. Only difference between inherited and not inherited is in "documentation sub window" -> ... Member of ...

Only think which maybe helps to extend the object in the tree. There you hava a folder "Base Type".

Comment: Thank you, that's unfortunate. I'll wait longer, may be someone knows a better way to investigate classes and their members inheritance.